# how to delete using data_migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, data-migration

I wanted to know how to complete this method to delete conversation classes from September 7th, 2021 onwards

```
class RemovesConversationClass < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    ConversationClass.where("created_at > ")destroy_all
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end

end
```

Comment: I would recommend making this a one-off rake task or script you run elsewhere, rather than something you run via an ActiveRecord migration.

Comment: @KelseyHannan It's pretty easy to forget to run some rake tasks if you have a big project with a plethora of such one-time rake tasks that you should run after deployment. How to manage all of this? How do not forget about some of that rake tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get time like so `Time.new(2021, 9, 7)`

```
ConversationClass.where("created_at > ?", Time.new(2021, 9, 7)).destroy_all
```

should work. But you should test it in your development environment first before you use it in production.

Comment: Just edited a typo it should be of course `Time.new` instead of `Time.now`